# I am currently trying to connect MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database in PHP, but it is not working. Here is my code.

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "username"; 
$db_pass = "pass"; 
$db_name = "login"; 


@mysql_connect ("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL"); 
@mysql_connect_db("$db_name") or die ("No database"); 


echo "Successful Connection"; 



?>
```

Comment: mysql_connect_db should be mysql_select_db

Comment: What error do you get? Wait, you won't get one since you suppress errors. Get rid of the `@`. That's a bad practice here.

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli and add proper error handling. Not error supressing.

Comment: What do u mean @JohnConde

Comment: Use mysql_select_db, the following could be some help.(http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) to connect to a MySQL database, not the mysql functions. They are deprecated, insecure, and will be removed from PHP in the future.

For mysqli:

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Connection Failed (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

For PDO:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_pass);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection Failed: $e->getMessage()";
```

Answer (score 2):

It's considered good practice to use the PDO interface to interact with a database using PHP. From the PHP docs:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

In your case you would substitute your username, database name and password in the first few lines.

[Read more here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) (PHP docs)

[Read even more here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338) (tutorial on basic SQL operations using PDO)

NB, avoid using the '@' symbol when debugging. This will hide any errors your code generates.